# Tratamento de url amigável por htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Tenho o seguinte código .htacess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\.meusite\.com.br$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://meusite.com.br/shop/ [P]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Queria fazer tudo que está em: "http://meusite.com.br/shop/produtos" ficar com a url amigável: "http://shop.meusite.com.br/produtos".

OBS: Meu portal é feito em Wordpress e os produtos são tratados pelo plugin "WooCommerce".

Comment: Não duplique e não poste na area errada, tenha mais atenção por favor. Marquei a outra como duplicata desta pois esta aqui esta mais completa, se quiser adicionar informações a pergunta clique no link editar.

Comment: Tem muitas postagens sobre URL amigável e .htaccess no site, grande chance disto já ter sido respondido (e mais de uma vez, inclusive). Use esta pesquisa aqui e veja qual resolve melhor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess+URL